# Responsive web vertical scrolling design and elements

Tags: responsive-design, carousel

I have been trying to implement a vertical scrolling site that is also responsive.
For that purpose, I have not used a responsive grid, only media queries. But I do have some blanks to be filled and I was hoping that you might shed some light.

First of all, I haven't used grids because I need elements to be contained either in the 100% width/height of viewport, or the 1200px Width/100% Height (and responsively to lower viewport sizes) of the viewport. My top tier screen is 1920x1080.

I have laid down some screens (mainly they are slices in the same viewport, for example 3 or four columns), but my problem is with a circular content carousel that is contained on 1200px and displays 3 columns at each time with a simple image and text below. Up to the ipad break-point (1024px - landscape or 768px portrait) it works fine. But when I go to the iphone breakpoints all hell breaks loose.

1. How can I implement the responsiveness on the carousel? Are there ways for example to have this on larger screens as a three column carousel, but what do I do when it comes to mobile devices?
2. Is vertical scrolling site compatible with the responsive web design or is it a bad tactic?

Comment: Your question seems very implementation centered. What is your user experience concern here, specifically?

Comment: Mostly how the carousel would be user friendly. Where should I ask about the implementation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/ is the place for concrete how-to code questions. Could you provide mock-ups or screenshots (links to those, if you can't insert the images yourself yet as new user) of things that look or work in a problematic way? With your question describing different screensizes and scenarios, it is a bit hard to really pin down what is the thing that causes you trouble.

Comment: Because most carousels work with absolute positioning, you would need to change it by modifying the javascript. It's not difficult to do, but if you haven't worked with js you will need help. You would be replacing the fixed widths the carousel calculates for dynamic ones based on the current size of the window. But it is something that can be done, so there's no problem combining carousels with responsive design. And there are some plugins that are ready for responsive too.

Comment: Also see http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/ - this is a carousel that has a "responsive" setting.

Comment: Closing the question for now until you're able to provide to screenshots/mockups as requested. Also, the question is to focused on implementation not ux so if you can improve that too we can reopen the question.

Comment: Sure, but I gave the tip to Benny, since he has an insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can imagine that. I think you need to discard the carousel on a certain (iPhone-ish) width and implement a user-controled carousel - like the Swedish newspaper Expressen:

[image]

Below the big header you see navigation arrows, and a red marker besides three gray ones. These are a carousel implemented on iPhone width fully user controlled. This is the same carousel viewed on the web:

[image]

On the web it all moves (annoyingly), but on the iPhone all is still. Nicely implemented! Do the same and you'll get my cheers!